# Numpy does not restore dimensions correctly (tofile and fromfile calls)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to save and restore from a file

```
arr.tofile("saved_arr.npy", sep=" ") #shape is (4, 5000, 5000)
arr = np.fromfile("saved_arr.npy") #shape is (278564007, )
```

How do I correctly restore ndarray of `(4, 5000, 5000)` shape?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not using [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`numpy.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) because you need the output written as a text file.  These methods restore your NumPy array as is with the dimensions.  If you use [`tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) and [`fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html), they write the output in C order, meaning that it by default unravels the data into a 1D array one row at a time.  You'd need to call the [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method on your array to get it back to the desired dimensions.  Also, make sure you specify the right separator.  You omitted this in the `fromfile` call, meaning that the file should be treated as binary.

If you must use these methods try:

```
arr.tofile("saved_arr.npy", sep=" ")
arr = np.fromfile("saved_arr.npy", sep=" ").reshape((4, 5000, 5000))
```

Answer (score 1):

In python3, try the following.

```
import numpy as np
#make an array of your desired dimensions
arr = np.random.random((4, 5000, 5000))
print(f'The shape of my array is {arr.shape}. \n')
#save your array
print('saving your array \n')
np.save('arr.npy', arr)
#load your array
u = np.load('arr.npy')
#finally check if both arrays are equal
print(f'My arrays are equal: {np.array_equal(u, arr)}')
```

I hope it helps.